# Is there any benefits of using @nestjs/class-validator package instead of class-validator?

Tags: validation, nestjs, class-validator

In NestJS application, right now I am using class-validator to validate DTO and request payload. Is there any benefits if I shift to @nestjs/class-validator?

I found both packages are same.

#edited
Later I found @nestjs/class-validator is maintained by nestjs which is especially designed for nestjs projects.
And @nestjs/class-validator is more updated/maintained one.

Comment: "I found both packages are same." — this is an extremely blunt statement: "This branch is 319 commits ahead of typestack:master."

Comment: So what's the difference can you further explain? @skink

Comment: Later i found @nestjs/.class-validator is maintained by nestjs  which is especially designed for nestjs projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of now, `@nestjs/class-validator` is just a fork to keep `class-validator` dependencies up to date.

You can see all of non-updates changes here: https://github.com/nestjs/class-validator/pulls?q=is%3Apr+sort%3Aupdated-desc+is%3Amerged+-author%3Aapp%2Frenovate+-author%3Aapp%2Fdependabot+